# How to use void*

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I am imlementing a simple `merge` function and I have got stuck, as the compiler gives me errors that I cannot explain. Here is my `merge` function:

```
void merge(void *a, int beg, int middle, int end, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*
{
  std::stack<void*> first;
  std::stack<void*> second;

  for(int i = beg; i < middle; i++) {
   first.push(a+i);
  }
  for(int i = middle; i < end; i++) {
    second.push(a+i);
  }

  for(int i = beg; i < end; i++) {
    if(first.empty()) {
      void *tmp = second.top();
      second.pop();
      a+i = tmp;
    } else if(second.empty()) {
      void *tmp = first.top();
      first.pop();
      a+i = tmp;
    } else if(cmp(first.top(), second.top())) {
      void *tmp = first.top();
      first.pop();
      a+i = tmp;
    } else {
      void *tmp = second.top();
      second.pop();
      a+i = tmp;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
sort.h: In function `void merge(void*, int, int, int, int (*)(const void*, const void*))':
sort.h:9: error: pointer of type `void *' used in arithmetic
sort.h:12: error: pointer of type `void *' used in arithmetic
sort.h:19: error: pointer of type `void *' used in arithmetic
sort.h:19: error: non-lvalue in assignment
sort.h:23: error: pointer of type `void *' used in arithmetic
sort.h:23: error: non-lvalue in assignment
sort.h:27: error: pointer of type `void *' used in arithmetic
sort.h:27: error: non-lvalue in assignment
sort.h:31: error: pointer of type `void *' used in arithmetic
sort.h:31: error: non-lvalue in assignment
```

Can anyone help me? TIA.

Comment: How to use `void*`? Simple answer: don't. For experts only: don't unless you really have to.

Comment: Tough to avoid always when you are using something like pthreads though.

Comment: @Fanael I totaly agree, but I do experiments, just to pass my time.

Comment: @Fanael: Exactly. Unless you need to implement low level memory operations (like `memcpy`, `memmov`, `memset`) which you shouldn't be implementing yourself anyway (they're already there), don't use `void*`. If you do use them, wrap them far away in a happy little class or struct or something.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: So use the standard thread library instead.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Ah, I am very limited in my C++ knowledge.  I didn't realize that the standard thread library allowed you to avoid pthreads.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is not possible with `void*`, since `void` has no size, and pointer arithmetic requires to compute memory addresses based on the size of the type.

If you expect `beg`, `middle` and `end` to represent *byte offsets*, you should use `char` pointers instead (one `char` is one byte).

If you want to write a *generic function*, that works with any type, don't use `void` pointers but templates:

```
template <typename t>
void merge(T *a, int beg, int middle, int end, int (*cmp)(const T*, const T*))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nice, but this is not what i'm seeking for.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes: You are asking why you are getting compile errors and every answer he explains it to you.  If this is not what you are looking for, you should consider rephrasing your question!

Comment: In this case, why not use iterators instead of pointers and `AnyFunc cmp` instead of a function pointer? That would be *truly* generic.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer - you are correct, I was assuming the definition of a byte as 8 bits, but it seems that is historically incorrect (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) - the size of char is defined as the platform's "byte" and can be larger than 8 bits.  Learned something today (and original comment removed).

Answer (score 1):

In `first.push(a+i);`, you are trying to add an offset `i` to a `void *` pointer `a`. This is illegal.

You can add offsets to any other "something pointer", because that something will be defined and will have a defined size in memory. Therefore adding an offset of 1 will mean moving forward of `sizeof(something)` in memory. But `void` has no defined size. Therefore you cannot use offsets with `void *` pointers.

Comment: It is not quite "any other something pointer" - if the something is an incomplete type it will still fail to compile because the correct size of the object cannot be determined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `void*` is that it is an address without a type. When you ask for `a+i` you say "move `i` elements further" without specifying what kind of elements. Is it one byte, one int, one car, one house, or one continent?

In C++ you don't have to use this kind of stuff, you can use templates and let the compiler figure out how to handle different types.

```
template<class T>
void merge(T* a, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Function prototype probably should look something like this:

```
void merge(void **a, int beg, int middle, int end, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*));
```

Then you can access every array member by its index without any problem.

Note: The size of object pointed by void is unknown as previously mentioned by Ferdinand (therefore a + i can't  be applied), but the size of void* is known therefore updating prototype in a such way does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you about one of your errors. You're trying to do pointer arithmetic on a `void*`. You see, when you add to a pointer, you are adding however many bytes there are in the type of the pointer. So, if you add to a `void*`, the compiler can't know how many bytes to add, as `void*` has no type. Therefore, if you want to do it at the byte level, cast to a `char*`, or any other pointer level you want. If you want to do things byte by byte, you can take a `void*`, but cast to `char*`.